# Spring Batch - restartable process with memory DB

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Spring Batch with memory DB - I have Spring Batch process using H2 memory DB (for  performance purposes).

It is multistep and multithread process working pretty well so far but one of requirements is to make it restartable (and recoverable) on failure.

Now the process is designed to terminate Spring Boot apliction when finished (or crashed).

My question is how can I add restart functionality without changing DB for file based or without compromising the performance in general?

One of ideas is to add another step executed on failure dumping db to files but what then? How to make process to recover out of that?

Comment: About your claim that the DB disk operations will cripple the performance, have you measured it? I expect that the job repository operations are negligible compared to your data if the latter is big. If you want to allow restart and recover, either you use a regular DB, or the file-based in-memory.

Comment: Yes, I measure it indeed. The thing is I am processing from 5 to 50 milion records per run and everything matters then, even the machine it is running on which is virtual in this case and disk operations are not the strongest part of it. Initially I had Derby DB but it let me down (it cannot cope wth such a volume properly and read/write become a pain when 1000 threads do that concurently).

Comment: Why are you not just using a regular DB?

Answer (score 0):

You just can configure your H2 instance to being persisted in file:

```
jdbc:h2:[file:][<path>]<databaseName>
jdbc:h2:~/test
jdbc:h2:file:/data/sample
jdbc:h2:file:C:/data/sample (Windows only)
```

Please [check h2 documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html)

Comment: Yes  I can do this but this will inevitably criple the app performance since disk operations are always slower than memory. Besides, this "small" change has implications in form of db maintence which need to be taken care of since then. This is actually another reason for using mem DB. So the question reemains open: how can I add restart functionality without changing DB for file based or without compromising the performance

Comment: Then you need normal DB, as in-memory's db feature is that it lives within applications memory, and if app is closed, you loose your data.

Comment: Well, I disagree here. I can alway dump DB into CSV files on failure and I prove that already. It works as far as the failure is not fatal. So this way I have my db state saved similar to regular DB. I can then develop a code loading that files into the database on next start. Let's say I will do that only on failure so that clean run do not save db state. My csv file(s) will contain just one single instance then, the one which failed. However how can I actually restart the job from that? Is my job config going to change somehow or not?